# Service Worker Install fails: "cannot read property 'addAll of undefined"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, service-worker

So I'll keep this succinct: When trying to install, my service worker fails. This is all of my code in `sw.js`:

```
var cacheName = 'randomstring';
var filesToCache = [ '/' ];

self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName)
            .then(function (cache) {
                console.log('[ServiceWorker] About to fail');
                return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            })
    );
});
```

I get an exception because `cache` is `undefined` (on the `cache.addAll` bit).

Not really sure why this is the case?

I've used service workers before and never encountered this issue. This is my first time using a service worker with an ASP.Net back-end though, so not sure if that's the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I figured this out. I was going to vote to close the question, but I figured I'd leave it here as I saw some other people with this issue who didn't know how to resolve it. Even though it's super-stupid :) (or more accurately, I am).

So I was running the website via the "Play" button, aka "Start Debugging", which, in Visual Studio 2017, launches a special Chrome window, in which the above error will be thrown.

To work around the issue, I can (or you can, internet traveller of the future) simply start without debugging, host the website in IIS, etc.

EDIT: If there's a better workaround where I can use the service worker in debug mode, please suggest it and I'll mark that as the answer. For my specific problem though, the above workaround is fine :).

Comment: This issue is pretty old at this point, but if anyone else is running in to this, the root cause is actually an odd Chrome bug (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1054541) where if the --user-data-dir path set when Chrome is launched is longer than 133 characters, the Cache API stops working. Visual Studio sets this to a custom (and long-ish) path to give you a fresh instance of Chrome for debugging (e.g. without extra extensions, clean cache, etc.).

Comment: The workaround that @Ceffis mentions below (using the "Browse With..." option in VS) should work well until the Chromium bug is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Encountered the same problem and found some other ways.

VS recognises "chrome.exe" while debugging and adds some parameters, that´s why service workers won´t working.

There is an option Debug => Option => Debugging => General => Enable javascript debugging for asp.net (Chrome, Edge and FireFox). If you don´t want to use js debugging in vs - like me because i use chrome for js debugging - just deactivate this option and service workers will work.
[VS Enable JS Debugging in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SQGn.png)

Alternatively you can add chrome as a new "browser" and switch the browser for debugging. Because vs recognise "chrome.exe" make a symlink via administative commandline "mklink chromedirect.exe chrome.exe" and add it as new browser in visual studio.

This can be done under the "Play" context menu => Browse with.
[VS Play Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGrAj.png)

Just add chromedirect.exe without any arguments and a friendly name like "Google Chrome Direct". After that you can switch to the browsers and select if you want VS JS Debugging or not.